# MapBox GL JS not working on mobile

Tags: ios, mobile, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've created a web map with MapBox GL JS and it is working well on desktop. It is uploaded here:
http://slow-data.com/webmap/barwifi.html.

Anyway on mobile (IOS) it is not loading at all. Do you know what code I need to make it working on mobile too? Here's the code I'm using right now
https://github.com/jp1312/wland/tree/master/MapBox_GL_JS

Thanks,

Jacopo

Comment: You should debug it like any other mobile web app. Look for error messages in the console, etc.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am a newby in web application so I am not sure I've got your message. How can I look for error messages in the console? Do you mean that when I try to open the map on Safari, let's say, there's a way from the mobile itself to debug and see what is happening behind the scenes?